# How to plot in R regression residuals by a numeric variable according categories of a column?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, charts, facet-wrap

My dataset follows this structure:

```
Column1 Column2 Column3 Categories
20  0   21  Category1
18  1   21  Category1
18  0   28  Category1
21  2   27  Category1
21  2   27  Category1
21  2   23  Category1
28  2   23  Category1
27  1   39  Category1
23  2   21  Category1
23  2   21  Category1
27  0   33  Category2
23  1   23  Category2
23  2   4   Category2
39  2   6   Category2
21  1   9   Category2
25  1   77  Category2
25  5   49  Category2
23  4   21  Category2
18  2   2   Category2
22  1   33  Category2
21  1   55  Category3
29  1   54  Category3
29  2   8   Category3
24  2   9   Category3
24  1   23  Category3
22  0   40  Category3
21  1   39  Category3
21  0   12  Category3
27  1   22  Category3
18  3   27  Category3
```

I aim to test residuals of `lm(Column1 ~ Column2) ~ Column3`, according `Categories`:

```
regression <- by(data, data$Categories, function(x) summary(lm(resid(lm(Columns1 ~ Columns2)) ~ Columns3, data = x)))

regression
```

How can I plot `resid(lm(Columns1 ~ Columns2)) ~ Columns3` according `Categories` with `ggplot2`, using `facet_wrap`? (or without `ggplot`?). Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add the residuals as a column to your data frame, then you can plot `residuals` by any column you want. If you wanna test the differences in residuals over the categories, you can plot bars with error bars, for example.

Ex. 1:

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(1)

df = data.frame(
  Column1 = sample(15:50, 30, replace = TRUE),
  Column2 = sample(0:1, 30, replace = TRUE, prob = c(.6,.4)),
  Column3 = sample(5:50, 30, replace = TRUE),
  Categories = sample(c("Category1", "Category2", "Category3"), 30, replace = TRUE)
)

mod1 = lm(Column1 ~ Column2, df)

df$residuals = mod1$residuals

df |> ggplot(aes(x = Column1, y = residuals, color = Categories)) +
  geom_point()
```

[image: Example chart]

Ex. 2: Grouping by `Categories`

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(1)

df = data.frame(
  Column1 = sample(15:50, 30, replace = TRUE),
  Column2 = sample(0:1, 30, replace = TRUE, prob = c(.6,.4)),
  Column3 = sample(5:50, 30, replace = TRUE),
  Categories = sample(c("Category1", "Category2", "Category3"), 30, replace = TRUE)
)

getResiduals = function(DF,...){
  model = lm(Column1 ~ Column2, DF)
  
  data.frame(DF, residuals = model$residuals)
}

out = df |> 
  group_by(Categories) |> 
  group_modify(getResiduals)

out |> ggplot(aes(x = Column3, y = residuals, color = Categories)) +
  geom_point()
```

[image: Graph 2]

In the 2nd example, the function `getResiduals` is applied to subsets of data according to `Categories`.

Comment: Can you add an R example?

Comment: What kind of plot do you want?

Comment: I just added a plot by `Column1`, but you can replace it. If you want, it is possible to use `facet_wrap` instead of `color` argument.

Comment: Yes, it will, just use `facet_wrap(~Category) ` without `color` argument.

Comment: On second thought, this solution, while elegant, still doesn't solve my problem, as I intend to calculate the residuals of `Column1 ~ Column2 ~ Column3` for each category particularly. Your codes calculate overall residuals, but not for each category individually. I am very grateful for your answer, and even more if you could help me in this regard.

Comment: If you want to determine the residuals taking into account `Column3` just do `lm(Column1 ~ Column2 + Column3)`. But if the requirement is observe the relation between the residuals of `Column1 ~ Column2` and `Column3`, just fit a second model like `lm(mod1$residuals ~ Column3)`. It is also possible add `Category` as a predictor to your LM.

Comment: What I mean is that there is a difference between: `plot(resid(lm(data$Column1[data$Category == "Category1"] ~ data$Column2[data$Category == "Category1"])) ~ data$Column3[data$Category == "Category1"])` and `plot(data$residuals[data$Category == "Category1"] ~ data$Column3[data$Category == "Category1"])`

Comment: I added an example where I apply a function to subsets of the data: function `group_modify` allows one to evaluate a function that has data frames as input and output in the groups of a grouped dataset. I think it's exactly what you want.